# How to add heyperlink in xml

Tags: xml

I want to add a hyperlink to the keywords in xml file. I googled and found the below solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<homepage xlink:type="simple"
xlink:href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</homepage>
</bookstore>
```

but it is not working as expected. And my requirement is different for example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<homepage>you are in home page you can search your favorite book. 
<anchor xlink:type="simple"
xlink:href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</anchor>
</homepage>
```

I want to add a hyper links to particular word in the para in xml  file.

Answer (score 0):

XML is a format for designing your own data formats.

It doesn't support hyperlinks per se. The [XLink specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XLink) provides a standard way to describe hyperlinks for XML, but requires specific client support.

If you are writing webpages, use HTML. You can store data in XML (but a real database is usually a better solution) and use server side code to convert it to HTML before sending it to the browser.